# logistic regression predicts 1 for all samples

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, prediction

I am trying to train a logistic regression model with data as follows:
Categorical Variable: either 0 or 1
Numerical Variables: Continuous number between 8 and 20

I have 20 numerical variables and I want to only use one at a time for the predicting model, and see which is the best feature to use.

The code I'm using is:

```
for variable in numerical_variable:
    X = data[[variable ]]
    y = data[categorical_variable]

    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=0)

    logreg = LogisticRegression()
    logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred=logreg.predict(X_test)
    print(y_pred)

    cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

    print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Precision:", metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Recall:", metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The categorical variable is biased towards 1, there are about 800 1s to 200 0s. So I think this is why it always predicts one, regardless of the test samples (if I don't set random_state=0) and regardless of the numerical variable.
(using python 3)

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried different sampling methods? I would try SRS and other methods. Your input data definitely seems skewed but that shouldn't be a big deal because the logR should learn from the attributes per entity, not the metadata of the dataset. The problem seems to be in the input layer imo.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at this - I've also tried using logreg = logisticRegression(class_weight = 'balanced') which has helped, now 0 gets predicted sometimes too. With similar accuracy to when everything was 1.

Comment: Evidently, the model does not have enough data to claim something as 0 (due to small sample size). Because gradient descent is always trying to minimize the error, your model is saying that it is better to guess everything as 1 rather than giving some entities 0, as it would lower it's overall accuracy. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, so is you suggestion still to used SRS and other sampling methods?

Comment: Well, you are limited by your data. Unless you have more samples that are 0, you won't be able to do much. But yes, varying sampling methods will definitely surpass this error.

Answer (score -2):

use `joblib` library to save your model,

```
import joblib
your_model = LogisticRegression()
your_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
joblib.dump(your_model, filename)
```

this code will save your model as 'finalized_model.sav'. the extension doesn't matter,even if you don't write.

then you can call your exact and fixed model by this code to take the same predictions all the time.

```
your_loaded_model = joblib.load('finalized_model.sav')
```

as a prediction example;

```
your_loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I don't understand how this helps with the predictions always being 1.

Comment: entirely misunderstood your trouble, thought you wanted to take always same prediction (without different randomness) but it's okay if you found a solution of your problem